# Making Loader object as singleton in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-loadermanager, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the Sqlite loader lib by commonsware i.e [cwac-loaderex](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex). Is it good practise to make Sqlite loader object as singleton?.

Lets say like, in a new activity i want to insert a new record, so i have to perform this operation on Loader object to get it reflected on my UI.

But in new activity, i dont want to load all the contents of table like this

```
loader=
        new SQLiteCursorLoader(this, db, "SELECT _ID, title, value "
            + "FROM constants ORDER BY title", null);
```

Instead, is it good to use the shared loader object via singleton?

EDIT:

**`yes i know its deprecated. Here my question is. Lets say that i have created a sqlite loader object and displayed the contents on listview, and i will click on add new item button, it will take me to a new activity, ill fill out the details and press add. In this case the added object to reflect on listview we need to perform insert operation on sqliteloader object, so should i have to pass this object from listview via intent or is it ok to create a new sqliteloader object in the current activity and perform operation?`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using the Sqlite loader lib by commonsware i.e cwac-loaderex.

Please don't. That project is discontinued, as is mentioned in all-caps boldface on the project home page.

> Is it good practise to make Sqlite loader object as singleton?.

No.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my answer in bold color, could you please tell me is the way i'm representing right or not. I know its deprecated but i need it still because i'm in the mid of my project. thanks

Comment: @Naruto: "so should i have to pass this object from listview via intent or is it ok to create a new sqliteloader object in the current activity and perform operation?" -- neither. You should have a singleton `SQLiteDatabase` instance (**NOT** `SQLiteCursorLoader`), and your second activity should use the `SQLiteDatabase` object to modify the database. You will need to rewrite `SQLiteCursorLoader` to have some option for you to manually tell it to reload the `Cursor` when you return to the first activity.

Comment: I did it like this, `public void refreshTheTaskList()
{
 if(mTLoader == null)
 {
     getLoaderManager().restartLoader(mSelectedListID,null,this);
 }
 else
 {
  mTLoader.onContentChanged();
 }
}`. 
It worked. Thank you very much for your help. Thanks lot